# Taylor Expansion of Composition of Functions

Tags: taylor-expansion, function-and-relation-composition

I have in my lecture notes that 
$$f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))\approx f'(g(x))\left(g(x+h)-g(x)\right)+f''(g(x))(g(x+h)-g(x))^2$$

He explained can found via taylor expansion, but I try to expand it and am not getting this answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For brevity in notation, let $y := g(x)$ and $k:= \def\k{g(x+h) - g(x)}\k$. Then, by Taylor's formula,
\begin{align*}
 & f\bigl(g(x+h)\bigr) - f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) \\&= f(y+k) - f(y)\\
     &= f'(y)k + \frac 12 f''(y)k^2 + o(k^2)\\
     &= f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\bigl(\k\bigr) + \frac12 f''\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\bigl(\k\bigr)^2 + o\Bigl(\bigl(\k\bigr)^2\Bigr)
\end{align*}
So you missed a $\frac 12$.

Comment: Did you mean to write k=g(x+h)-g(x)

Comment: @Kamster Right, thx. Edited.

Comment: Dang that makes perfect sense I was overthinking it